# Interpretación correcta de Not en VB .Net en estructura If

Tags: vb.net, operador, estructuras

Me he topado con una interrogante a un caso particular, comparto el código, es básicamente un evento Clic de botón cualquiera.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
   
    Dim str As String = "33333323"

    If str.IndexOf(".") Then
        MsgBox("" & str.IndexOf("."))
    End If

    Dim str2 As String = "888882.33"
    If str2.IndexOf(".") Then
        MsgBox("" & str2.IndexOf("."))
    End If

    If True And Not str.IndexOf(".") Then
        MsgBox("x " & str.IndexOf("."))
    End If

    If True And Not str2.IndexOf(".") Then
        MsgBox("y " & str2.IndexOf("."))
    End If

End Sub
```

Mi duda surge en lo siguiente:
el método `IndexOf` de una cadena devuelve -1 si no encuentra la subcadena buscada dado como parámetro, devuelve 0 si es un espacio en blanco y devuelve un numero o índice en base 0 de encontrarlo.

He realizado 2 if para comparar cómo interpreta los resultados cuando se evalúa los casos. Por ejemplo `If str.IndexOf(".")` y  `If str2.IndexOf(".")` en ambos casos se muestra un mensaje con los valores devueltos. Esto demostraría que hay una conversión implícita que arroja True en ambos if por lo que muestra el mensaje, de lo contrario alguno de ellos no se mostraría.
Luego armé otros 2 estructuras de If pero esta vez incluyendo el operador And y Not...y aquí es lo que desconcierta... por qué el valor `If True And Not str2.IndexOf(".")` es Verdadero??? ya que el mensaje contenido se muestra... En este if `If True And Not str.IndexOf(".")` es lógico que no se muestre ya que el `str.IndexOf(".")` es Verdadero y se vuelve False lo que hace que el mensaje contenido en el tercer If no se muestre pero sí el  del cuarto If

Alguien que pueda explicar por favor...

Tengo visual studio 2023.

---

[image: entra el primer if]

[image: entra al segundo if]

[image: al tercer if no entra y tiene lógica pero entra al cuarto if... este último no tiene lógica..]

Como se en la última imagen se ve que al cuarto if ingresa... esto último no tiene lógica. Tal vez sea un bug en la versión del compilador. Es posible.
Espero que las imágenes se puedan entender. Muchas gracias por responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

- `StringEntrada.IndexOf(argumento)`: Retorna el índice (posición) del string `argumento` dentro del `StringEntrada`, va de `0 a N` siendo N el largo del StringEntrada -1, y cero porque en programación contamos desde el cero. Luego retorna `-1` cuando el string `argumento` no ha sido encontrado. Además retorna `0` cuando el `argumento` es vacío (que es muy distinto a un espacio como tu has señalado)
- En `VB` 0 es equivalente a `False` y cualquier otro número es equivalente a `True`

Entonces

```
"33333323".IndexOf(".")) ' -1
"888882.33".IndexOf(".") ' 6
```

En ambos casos da un valor distinto a cero, y como dije arriba, cualquier valor distinto a cero se evalúa como `True`. Razón por la cual se entra a estos 2 `if`

```
    If str.IndexOf(".") Then
        MsgBox("" & str.IndexOf("."))
    End If

    Dim str2 As String = "888882.33"
    If str2.IndexOf(".") Then
        MsgBox("" & str2.IndexOf("."))
    End If
```

---

Ahora el problema es con el `Not`, este operado trabaja tanto con booleanos como con números. El cual realiza una negación lógica de una expresión Booleana o **una negación bit a bit de una expresión número**

Dicho de otro modo si haces `Not Bool` el Not trabaja como operador lógico, pero si hacer `Not número` trabaja como operador binario

#### 1er Caso

*Eliminaré los `True And` porque solo aportan ruido*

```
    If Not str.IndexOf(".") Then
        MsgBox("x " & str.IndexOf("."))
    End If
```

Paso a paso:

- str.IndexOf(".") es `-1`
- `Not -1` es `0`
- cero es False

#### 2do Caso

Donde si entra a la condición

```
    If Not str2.IndexOf(".") Then
        MsgBox("x " & str.IndexOf("."))
    End If
```

- str2.IndexOf(".") es `6`
- `Not 6` es `-7`
- -7 es distinto a cero, entonces es `True` y por eso entra

---

Si conviertes a `Boolean` con anticipación, no tendrías el problema, porque el Not trabajará para booleanos

```
     If True And Not Convert.ToBoolean(str.IndexOf(".")) Then
         Console.WriteLine("ENTRA STR")
     End If

     If True And Not Convert.ToBoolean(str2.IndexOf(".")) Then
         Console.WriteLine("ENTRA STR2")
     End If
```

Comment: Pero sí entra a entra al segundo... y es eso lo que me desconcierta... al menos en mi ejecución de visual studio que tengo sí ingresa... mira las imágenes por favor:

Comment: @JuanDavidMondalgo Ahh ya entendi!! He actualizado la respuesta

Comment: Hola @Yussef. Disculpa. No te agradecí la respuesta, con ella la respuesta está completa. Muchas gracias.